Git remote add link issue
I don't know if this is a dumb question, but why we add '.git' to the end of our Github repo url while specifying the remote url? Because I just used it without '.git', like:
git remote add origin https://github.com/<my-nick>/<repo-name>
instead:
git remote add origin https://github.com/<my-nick>/<repo-name>.git
and it worked.
So, is there any specific reason to add that?

It specifies that the repository is a bare Git repository hosted on a remote server (in this case, GitHub)
A bare repository is one that does not have a working directory.
Simply, it is just a convention.
